# How can I configure mono to use the correct paths to etc/ directory when the prefix directory is relocated?

Tags: mono

I have compiled mono 2.10.9 and 3.0.3 on linux and would like to be able to move these installations to a different location without recompiling. The problem I am having is that mono-sgen is unable to find the etc/ directory after relocation. Interestingly, mono using the boehm GC *is* able to find that directory after relocation. Is there a reason the two executables behave differently?

I have been able to specify the updated library paths using MONO_PATH like this:

```
export MONO_PATH=${PKG_DIR}/lib/mono/4.0:${PKG_DIR}/lib/mono/3.5:${PKG_DIR}/lib/mono/2.0:${PKG_DIR}/lib/mono/compat-2.0
```

but I am stuck on getting mono-sgen to find the etc/ directory. The exception I am receiving as a result is:

```
ConfigurationErrorsException: Error Initializing the configuration system.
```

If recompiling mono with the new prefix is the easiest solution I will go that route, but hopefully there is something else I can do to get this working. It's nice when you can relocate an entire program with all its dependencies and it still works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question above is:

```
export MONO_CONFIG=${PKG_DIR}/etc/mono/config
export MONO_CFG_DIR=${PKG_DIR}/etc
```

However, there are a number of other environment variables you may need to set to get a relocated mono installation fully working. Read on...

I was able to get this working. It turns out there are a number of variables that need to be set to make the relocation work correctly. The following code assumes the mono installation was moved to `${PKG_DIR}`. I moved all the fonts I needed to `${PKG_DIR}/etc/fonts` so that they would be found if the installation was moved to a different system. Here are the environment variables I used. Some of these may not be necessary:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PKG_DIR/lib64:$PKG_DIR/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_RUN_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_DIR/lib64/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
export MONO_GAC_PREFIX=${PKG_DIR}
export MONO_PATH=${PKG_DIR}/lib/mono/4.0:${PKG_DIR}/lib/mono/3.5:${PKG_DIR}/lib/mono/2.0:${PKG_DIR}/lib/mono/compat-2.0
export MONO_CONFIG=${PKG_DIR}/etc/mono/config
export MONO_CFG_DIR=${PKG_DIR}/etc
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=${PKG_DIR}/include
export ACLOCAL_PATH=${PKG_DIR}/share/aclocal
export FONTCONFIG_PATH=${PKG_DIR}/etc/fonts
export XDG_DATA_HOME=${PKG_DIR}/etc/fonts
export MONO_REGISTRY_PATH=~/.mono/registry
```